# Suppose $M\models D(N)$. Show that $M$ has a substructure which is isomorphic to $N$

Tags: logic, problem-solving

> Let $N$ be an $L$-structure. The diagram of $N$, denoted $D(N)$, is the set of all quantifier-free $L_N$-sentences which are true in $N$.
>
> 1. Suppose $M$ is a model of $D(N)$. Show that $M$ has a substructure
>    which is isomorphic to $N$.
> 2. Conversely, suppose that $M$ is an $L$-structure such that $N$ is
>    isomorphic to a submodel of $M$. Show that $M$ can be made into an
>    $L_N$-structure which is a model of $D(N)$.

**My attempt**:

1. Let $\beta: N\to M: n\mapsto c_n^M$ (the interpretation in $M$ of the constant associated to $n$). This is an injective function, because $\neg(c_n = c_{n'})\in D(N)$ for $n\ne n'$. Now, it remains to show that $N':= \beta(N)$ is a substructure of $M$.

*Definition substructure*: Let $M$ and $N$ be structures for a language $L$. We say that $N$ is a substructure of $M$ if $N$ is a subset of $M$, and the following conditions are satisfied:

- For every constant $c$ of $L$, $c^N=c^M$.
- For every $n$-place function symbol $f$ of $L$, $f^N:N^n\to N$ is the restriction of $f^M$ to $N^n$.
- For every $n$-place relation symbol $R$ of $L$, $R^N=R^M\cap N^n$.

I'm not sure how to proceed from here on.

2. Let $\beta: N\to N' \le M$ be an isomorphism of $L$-structures. To make an $L_N$-structure, we add $\{c_n\mid n\in N\}$ to $L$. The structures $N$ and $N'$ must satisfy the same $L$-sentences.

For the newly added constants, I need to add $c_n^M$ to $M$. Now $c_n^M = c_n^{N'}$ (submodel), and $c_n^{N'} = \beta(c_n^N)$. So, I need to add these elements to $M$. I don't think that extra functions and relations need to be defined on $M$.

Is this it? I'm mostly looking for some help with question 1., which may possibly contain an interesting idea for 2.

Thanks.

Comment: For question 2, what do you mean by "Now $c^M_n=c^{N′}_n $(submodel), and $c^{N′}_n=β(c^N_n)$. $\textbf{So, I need to add these elements to M.}$" ?

Comment: I was thinking about the definition of structures. We want to 'make $M$ into an $L_N$-structure', so for each constant in $L_N$ we should have its interpretation in $M$ be contained in $M$. Maybe I misinterpreted 'making into an $L_N$-structure', I don't really see what is expected from question 2.

Comment: You are correct, you have to choose interpretations of the constants $c_n$ for $n \in N$. Now, do we have a privileged choice ? In fact, you wrote something that looks like that yourself.

Comment: I think $\beta(c_n^N) = \beta(n)$ is a good choice (since these are equal to $c_n^M$).

Comment: Yes. Now, can you check that it works ? I've edited my answer to add a hint. Edit : To be completely formal, $c_n^M$ hasn't been defined yet, since $M$ was just an $L$-structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hint for question 1 :

For relations, say, do you see why $N \models R(n_1,...,n_k)$ iff $M \models R(\beta(n_1),...,\beta(n_k))$, if $R$ is a relation symbol, and $n_1,...,n_k$ are elements of $N$ ?

Another hint for question 1 :

Assume we know that $\beta(N)$ is an $L_N$-structure isomorphic to $N$. Now, we may restrict the language, to view it as an $L$-structure. I claim that, if $f$ is a function symbol in $L$, say, of arity $1$, and $n \in N$, then $f^M(\beta(n)) \in \beta(N) $. Can you see why ? (It has to do with $M \models D(N)$)

For relations, what we have to check is that, if $x,y \in \beta(N)$, if $R$ is a relation (I'll let you deal with the arities, it's not hard), then $\beta(N) \models R(x,y)$ iff $M \models R(x,y)$.

Here, we have to recall that the interpretation of $R$ for $\beta(N)$ was defined in a certain way, using the map $\beta$ and the structure already defined on $N$. Then, as before, exploit the hypothesis
"$M \models D(N)$".

For question 2, the idea is similar. You have to exploit the fact that an isomorphism preserves quantifier-free formulas.

Hint : Can you define the $L_N$ structure on $M$ such that it induces an $L_N$ structure on $N'$ (which is currently a sub - $L$-structure of $M$) that would be isomorphic, as an $L_N$-structure, to $N$ ?

In other words, can you enrich the isomorphism of $L$-structures $N \simeq N'$ into an isomorphism of $L_N$-structures, by defining the obvious $L_N$-structure on $N'$ ?

Comment: $N\models R(n_1,\dots,n_k) \iff R(c_{n_1},\dots,c_{n_k})\in D(N) \iff M\models  R(c_{n_1},\dots,c_{n_k})$ (since $M$ is a model for $D(N)$. The interpretation of each $c_{n_i}$ in $M$ is just $\beta(n_i)$, which proves the equivalence?

Comment: @Zachary Yes, that is correct.

Comment: For 1, how does this show that $\beta(N)$ is a substructure? This equivalence for relations shows that $\beta$ is an $L$-isomorphism (of course, functions and constants need to be checked too), is this enough to say that $\beta(N)$ is a substructure of $M$?

Comment: We want to prove that $\beta(N)$ can be made into an $L$-substructure of $M$. First, note that the $L_N$-structure we put on $\beta(N)$ induces, by "restriction of the language", an $L$-structure on $\beta(N)$. To prove that this $L$-structure is in fact a substructure of $M$, we have to use the hypothesis that $M \models D(N)$.

Comment: @Zachary : I am sorry, I forgot to ask : what structure exactly do you put on $\beta(N)$ ? Do you want to put the one induced by $M$, or the one coming from the isomorphism $\beta$ ?

Comment: From the isomorphism, using the information from $N$.